# Llamado a página con SweetAlert2 [REST]

Tags: reactjs

tengo una duda. Tengo una alerta:

> import Swal from 'sweetalert2'

La cual me hace varios tipos de alertas dependiendo lo que haga en mi website. Hay una en especial, que quiero que al darle 'click' al botón, me lleve a otra página, entonces lo tengo de la siguiente manera:

```
})
Swal.fire({
    type: 'error',
    tile: '...',
    html: '...',
    showConfirmButton: true,
    confirmButtonText: 'link a donde quiero ir' + 'Nombre a mostrar' + 'Cierre de link',
})
return
```

Entonces, el botón me sale subrayado al tener link, leí la documentación de los SweetAlert2 y no hay ninguno que me de un ejemplo para links.

Gracias.

Comment: que link estas usando? una etiqueta `a` o un componente `Link` de react router? en cualquier caso tienes que quitarle los estilos `textDecoration: 'none'`. Me parece que lo mas recomendable es hacer el redireccionamiento de forma codificada osea agregale un `.then( () => {...})` despues de `Swal.fire` y dentro hacer el redireccionamiento

Comment: Estoy usando una etiqueta `a`, entonces, le agrego el `textDecoration` y agregar el `.then` luego?

Comment: Esto ya esta solucionado en este post. ¡Aquí está la respuesta [callback sweet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358423/how-to-redirect-page-after-click-on-ok-button-on-sweet-alert)!